# React-Native drawer menu open inside stack-Navigator screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

In my application I've 3 stack like
**StackOne**

```
export const StackOne = createStackNavigator({
  OneScreen: { screen:one  },
  TwoScreen: { screen:two  },
  ThreeScreen: { screen:three  },
}, { initialRouteName: 'OneScreen', }
);
```

**StackTwo**

```
export const StackTwo = createStackNavigator({
  OneScreenTwo: { screen:oneTwo  },
  TwoScreenTwo: { screen:twoTwo  },
  ThreeScreenTwo: { screen:threeTwo  },
}, { initialRouteName: 'OneScreenTwo', }
);
```

I use the drawer navigation like this.
**MainDrawer**

```
const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    One: { screen: StackOne },
    Two: { screen: StackTwo },
    Other: { screen: OtherScreen},
  },
  {}
);
```

All working fine. manage drawer - to stack very well 
only issue is when I'm in `StackOne's ScreenTwo` of swipe the left- right still open the drawer menu.
not only this screen in every screen open drawer menu.

I try several link but can't find the success.
Hope some one help.
I follow this link [Navigation](https://medium.com/async-la/react-navigation-stacks-tabs-and-drawers-oh-my-92edd606e4db)

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want the drawer to not respond to touch gestures when you are inside `StackOne`?

Comment: @QoP yes, I want disable drawer inside stack activity.
I use this but can't work.  
navigationOptions: {
      headerMode: "none",
      header: null,
      drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
      disableGestures: false,
      drawerPosition: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'left' : 'right',
    },

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh So, you need the drawer to only respond in `stackOne->ScreenOne`

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen yes, I want this, & it's working like this .but issue is he open in stack's subscreens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify `navigationOptions` on the StackNavigator instead of `TwoScreen` etc, as otherwise it'd be configuring the StackNavigator instead of the DrawerNavigator:

```
StackOne.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  drawerLockMode: navigation.state.index === 0 ? 'unlocked' : 'locked-closed',
});
```

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@riwu/stack-nav-lock-drawer

Comment: I applied same logic but then navigation not display.
drawer not opened !

Comment: Can you create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on https://snack.expo.io?

Comment: please wait I implement Another approach with this method 
& update you.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const StackOne = createStackNavigator({
  OneScreen: { screen:one  },
  TwoScreen: { screen:two  },
  ThreeScreen: { screen:three  },
}, { initialRouteName: 'OneScreen', }
);


StackOne.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = 'unlocked';
  if (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index] != 'OneScreen') {
    drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed';
  }
  return {
    drawerLockMode,
  };
};


export const StackTwo = createStackNavigator({
  OneScreenTwo: { screen:oneTwo  },
  TwoScreenTwo: { screen:twoTwo  },
  ThreeScreenTwo: { screen:threeTwo  },
}, { initialRouteName: 'OneScreenTwo', }
);

StackTwo .navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = 'unlocked';
  if (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index] != 'OneScreenTwo') {
    drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed';
  }
  return {
    drawerLockMode,
  };
};
```

Create navigation option & issue resolved.